# regex for testing quantity of matching characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a regex that tests whether a string has two or more of a list of characters, e.g 'i,j,k'

so my regex is

```
[ijk]{2,}
```

and the regex gets a match if the characters are contiguous:

```
abcdefghijk
```

but not if there are other interspersed characters like this:

```
abcdefghixjxk
```

and (i|j|k){2,} has the same issue

How to test for total characters found, not total characters found in succession?

Thanks

Comment: Can your input string contain `iaiaiaiaiaiai`? If so, would the total characters found be 7?

Comment: For the general case, yes it would be 7.  For my particular problem I just need to check for 2 or more, so two instances of the string get the code to work.  I had originally thought that regex quantifiers would be able to count the instances, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead to check for a second occurrence:

```
[ijk](?=.*[ijk])
```

This will match if an occurrence of i, j, or k is followed by another one after any (`.*`) number of other characters.

**Edit**

I guess the positive lookahead isn't strictly necessary (more force of habit), you could just use:

```
[ijk].*[ijk]
```

Comment: I was trying to simplify the example - there are actually half a dozen characters I am looking for.  So I'm looking for something that is more flexible than one character following another.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, that will work.  I thought it would be a simpler regex, but I guess not.  Thank you!

Comment: @FredAndrews you're right, it could be simpler. The positive lookahead is not required. See my edit.